# Why is my lighting frozen in a streak as my scene animates?

Tags: lighting

I turned off all volumetric lighting and it still did this, I'm rendering in EEVEE. I've tried changing settings, like ambient occlusion, turning off bloom, upping the sampling, turning off my volumetric in the scene, denoising, and everything I could think of.

Here's my .blend it's a google drive file and 600mgs plus I'm sorry but seemed best way to show whats wrong.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qDXGaC3W2WWfPaL2uzQ-61arOLOvQizR/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: how shall we help you if you showed us no settings at all and you didn't give us any useful information except eevee and volume lighting? So i would recommend you provide your blend file so we can check it out.

Comment: Oh sorry I will add more details and things, I rushed this post without thinking it over. Will add the .blend to the post

Comment: I added the .blend, and more information, but I can't honestly tell what's wrong, I fiddled with every setting I could think of and that chatgpt told me to try